# How do I generate random number with a range X times in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to generate a random number X times with a range. I've tried to create a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Random_Number (@Times INT, @Upper BIGINT,@Lower BIGINT, @randomvalue numeric(18,10))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Random BIGINT
    DECLARE @Row INT

    SET @Row = 1

    WHILE  @Row <= @Times
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Random = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * @randomvalue + @Lower), 0)
        SET @Row = @Row + 1
    END
    RETURN @Random
END
GO


select dbo.Random_Number(5,2002100001,2002100010,RAND())
```

The query only returns a single row:

```
#1 2002100003
```

I want the following result:

```
#1 2002100003
#2 2002100000
#3 2002100009
#4 2002100006
#5 2002100007
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Perhaps a recursive cte?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursive approach :

```
with cte as (
     select 2002100001 as st, 2002100010 as ed
     union all
     select c.st + 1, c.ed
     from cte c
     where c.st < c.ed
)
select top (5) st
from cte
order by newid();
```

Comment: Works like a charm! :-) This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @Leto . . . This does not allow duplicates.  That may or may not be a good thing, but you don't specify "without replacement" in the question.